# Building Java/Scala in Eclipse 2020-06 with bndtools fails

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, bndtools

- Bnd version: 5.1.2.202007211702
- Java version: java version "1.8.0_231"
- Eclipse version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

I am trying to migrate a large PDE based OSGi code base to bndtools but I am stuck with getting a project that contains Scala code working. The projects that only contain Java code work build perfectly.
I am using the Scala-IDE and added Scala nature to the project. Upon building this project I get the error / stacktrace attached below.

This is the .project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>com.sendrato.traxyz.positioning</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>bndtools.core.bndbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>bndtools.core.bndnature</nature>
        <nature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Does anyone has similar issues and knows how to solve this?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2020-08-15 11:10:48.050
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 75 2020-08-15 11:10:48.050
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Scala Builder' on project 'com.sendrato.traxyz.positioning'.
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [cnf does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(JavaElement.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getPerProjectInfoCheckExistence(JavaModelManager.java:2525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPerProjectInfo(JavaProject.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:2466)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject$.org$scalaide$core$internal$project$ScalaProject$$dependenciesForProject(ScalaProject.scala:127)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject$.$anonfun$exportedDependenciesForProjects$1(ScalaProject.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set2.foreach(Set.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject$.exportedDependenciesForProjects(ScalaProject.scala:144)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject.transitiveDependencies(ScalaProject.scala:207)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.SbtScopesBuildManager.$anonfun$findProjectsInError$3(SbtScopesBuildManager.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:352)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.SbtScopesBuildManager.findProjectsInError(SbtScopesBuildManager.scala:81)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.SbtScopesBuildManager.$anonfun$build$2(SbtScopesBuildManager.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:283)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.SbtScopesBuildManager.build(SbtScopesBuildManager.scala:47)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject.build(ScalaProject.scala:596)
    at org.scalaide.core.internal.builder.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:111)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: The exception is because the project doesn't have the Java nature

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also you may want to have a look at [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for helpful hints.

Comment: The project does have Java (and Scala) nature

Comment: The ScalaIDE calls internal stuff instead of using the public API of Eclipse. This might cause that the ScalaIDE (which has not been developed or maintained for a long time) does not work with the current Eclipse version anymore. Or maybe the ScalaIDE doesn't work with your project configuration (when you have a `module-info.java` file, try to delete it).